# How to get handle to replaced child?

Tags: javascript

```
obj.parentNode.replaceChild(elem,obj)
```

Now I want to have a handle to that inserted node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "elem" handle is still valid even if it has been inserted into the DOM.
So you can simply use elem to access the element that has replaced the old element.

Answer (score 1):

Use the reference you already have: `elem`. That's the element you just added. The `replaceChild` call doesn't create any new nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing something like this:

```
obj.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createElement('div'),obj)
```

...you'll not end up with any reference to the new element. You'll need to first retain it manually:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');  // Create & reference the new element

obj.parentNode.replaceChild(elem,obj);  // Perform the replace
```

[MDC Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.replaceChild)